# Use an image from the asset pipeline inside of a link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I want to create a link that uses an image from the asset pipeline. Image is stored at `assets/images/github_icon.png`.

Link tag without the image:

```
<%= link_to "Log in with Github", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %>
```

Link tag with the image (how do I create this one?):

```
<%= link_to ?????, omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %>
```

In the past I've used `raw()` when adding html within a link tag:

```
<%= link_to raw("<p>Hey kids!</p>"), ... %>
```

But I was unsure how I could use `raw()` with a `img_tag("github-icon.png")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**link_to**

Two ways:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("github_icon.png"), path %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to path do %>
    <%= image_tag "github_icon.png" %>
<% end %>
```

--

Like many Rails helpers, [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) is very flexible - you just need to pass the right arguments to it. You're trying to pass `img_tag` (which doesn't exist as a method), and `raw()` (which won't do anything).

You should use [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag), and won't need to use `raw`

Comment: Ahh beat me by seconds :D

Comment: You should mention in your answer that what you've got is a `code block`, not a `loop`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`link tag with block`](http://apidock.com/rails/v1.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to). Try

```
<%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) do %>
  Log in with Github
  <%= image_tag "github_icon.png" %>
<% end %>
```

Notice link_to block version doesn't take text so you'll have to add your text **Log in with Github inside block**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

1. `link_to image_tag("imageName.png", :border => 0), {:action => 'actionName', :controller => 'controllerName'}, {:class => 'className'}`

Or you can try this:

```
<%= link_to href: '/url/for/you' do %>
    <%= image_tag 'yourImage.jpg', width: 136, height: 67, alt: 'WIN!'%>
<% end %>
```